# MySQL query - Summation over interval

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Hello Stack Overflow community!

I've got a bit of a problem with my MySQL query.  What I'm after is a query that will return the sum of all the Project_Cost from a table, however I want it to split it into different sections per timeframes.  The kicker for me is that I want them to be split per *month* (Ex: all costs in June, July, August, etc.)

The way I have it set up presently is that it's splitting them in one month increments, but this is being determined by the current date.  So essentially this would only work on the first of the month, and from then on it's inaccurate.

Can somebody help me edit this query so that it'll give me what I'm after?  I've been testing a lot of approaches that I've seen but nothing is giving me what I'm after.

```
SELECT SUM(IF(DateSigned BETWEEN DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH)) AND NOW(),Project_Cost,0)) AS A,
    SUM(IF(DateSigned BETWEEN DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 MONTH)) AND DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH)),Project_Cost,0)) AS B,
    SUM(IF(DateSigned BETWEEN DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -3 MONTH)) AND DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 MONTH)),Project_Cost,0)) AS C,
    SUM(IF(DateSigned BETWEEN DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -4 MONTH)) AND DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -3 MONTH)),Project_Cost,0)) AS D,
    SUM(IF(DateSigned BETWEEN DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -5 MONTH)) AND DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -4 MONTH)),Project_Cost,0)) AS E,
    SUM(IF(DateSigned BETWEEN DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -6 MONTH)) AND DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -5 MONTH)),Project_Cost,0)) AS F,
    SUM(IF(DateSigned BETWEEN DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -7 MONTH)) AND DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -6 MONTH)),Project_Cost,0)) AS G
    FROM project
    WHERE program = '1';
```

Comment: You might want to look [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html); I think the `MONTH` (for grouping/range replacement) and `LAST_DAY`(for filtering data) functions would likely be helpful.

Comment: In my view, the methodology is wrong, would it not be better to create a summery table and have a cron job that aggregates this data at the end of each month.  It's a bit more to maintain, but performance would be orders of magnitude better, as would simplicity of use.  The only issue would be if data is changed outside of the month.  A lot of that depends on the particulars of your use case, but aggregating all this on the fly is like running 7 or 8 queries that have to summarize large chunks of data.  If it becomes static at some point, why query it more then once.

Comment: That's a very fair point, and I've thought about doing that too.  Ultimately I decided against it because I think the freedom to change these queries to provide different metrics later on would outweigh the downside to having all these queries running.  In addition, the Project Cost is subject to change outside of the month it was signed in which would make it a bit sloppy to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `YEAR(date)*12+MONTH(date)` to compare months:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(YEAR(DateSigned)*12+MONTH(DateSigned) = YEAR(Now())*12+MONTH(Now()),Project_Cost,0)) AS CurrentMonth,
       SUM(IF(YEAR(DateSigned)*12+MONTH(DateSigned) = YEAR(Now())*12+MONTH(Now())-1,Project_Cost,0)) AS PreviousMonth,
       SUM(IF(YEAR(DateSigned)*12+MONTH(DateSigned) = YEAR(Now())*12+MONTH(Now())-2,Project_Cost,0)) AS C
       /* etc... */
FROM   project
WHERE  program = '1'
```

Comment: Was exactly what I was after.  Thank you very much for your support.  This is sorting them perfectly by month.

Answer (score 0):

Could be i don't understand your  question but seems a group by (year and)  month

```
SELECT year(DateSigned), month(DateSigned), sum(Project_Cost)
from project 
WHERE program = '1'
Group By year(DateSigned), month(DateSigned)
```

Comment: This was a very good solution and did provide me with what I was after.  Unfortunately having to run a while loop made the rest of the implementation pretty messy for this scenario.